# How to hide keyboard without closing the dialog box using Appium for IOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, testng, appium, appium-ios

I have a dialog box that appears and while closing keyboard with `hideKeyboard();` all the form is closed and i get back to the home page so that i can't continue the scenario for filling other data.

Here the screen :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use UIScrollView in your dialog box, and set scroll view class TPKAScrollViewController. [Download class](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Comment: in which step ? when i open the dialog  i have about 10 step of filling data ?

Comment: UIScrollView will not work here as it is in the scope of automation.

Comment: Sorry i didn't use it before i don't have idea about it

Comment: You must create such struct of your controller : UIView -> UIScrollView -> Your view with dialog box

Comment: I m just writing automation scripts the app is ready ! 
Just to do some test senario !

Answer (score 1):

You can fill up the fields first using driver.sendkey() then tap on keyboard next button to switch the driver to the next field untill the last field. in last field you will get done button then you can tap on that button.

Answer (score 1):

The default "strategy" of `hideKeyboard();` is to tap outside the keyboard, but this can be changed to pressing a key on the keyboard instead.

See the java-client documentation (assuming you're using java-client?) for available hideKeyboard strategies: http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSDeviceActionShortcuts.html

If your app's keyboard has for example a "Next" button to close the keyboard with, then you could use: `driver.hideKeyboard("Next");`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions !
 i'will try with : driver.hideKeyboard("Return");