# How can i hide keyboard by tapping into the button with yellow circle?

Tags: ios, keyboard, testng, appium, appium-ios

I m using appium with java to automate my tests.
I want to know the name of the button that i have circled it in yellow color.
How can i hide keyboard by tapping into the button with yellow circle ?

[HERE the link for another question, but still have the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294659/how-to-hide-keyboard-without-closing-the-dialog-box-using-appium-for-ios)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use :

```
driver.hideKeyboard("Hide keyboard");
```

Comment: Thanks Amine for your answer, the problem is that hideKeyboard didn't accept any string into it . I can only tap `driver.hideKeyboard();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's Appium Inspector showing the details of the key:

[image]

So here's 2 different examples for hiding the keyboard:

`driver.hideKeyboard("Hide keyboard");`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'Hide keyboard')]").click();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Domestus, the first one i couldn't use it because hideKeyboard didn't accept any string into it . I can only tap `driver.hideKeyboard();` And the second solution had to work, but unfortunately it didn't i get another character tapped (extra 'z') in placeholder instead of keyboard is closed! !

Comment: If `hideKeyboard()` doesn't accept a string, you may be using an old version of the java-client. Latest version is 4.1.1. Otherwise it could be related to the driver you're using.

Are you using `AppiumDriver driver = new IOSDriver(url, caps);` ?

Comment: I'm using java client 3.4.1, ok i'll try to update it. Otherwise i'm using `AppiumDriver` :  `AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities)`

Comment: Looks like the `hideKeyboard()` that takes in strings is actually IOSDriver specific: http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSDriver.html#hideKeyboard(java.lang.String) so you'd need to cast your AppiumDriver into IOSDriver to gain access to the command. Otherwise you should still be able to try and figure a well working findElement command and `click()` on the button.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Please mark the answer accepted, if it helped you out! Let me know if any edits should be done in the current answer.